# Fill NULL based on conditions python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset, and needs to create a new column to deal with the NULL based on the conditions. Here is the sample data:

```
id1 id2 col1 col2 
1   1   2     3 
2   2   2     NULL
3   3   NULL  3
4   4   NULL  3
5   5   10    11
```

The expect output is

```
id1 id2 col1 col2  combine
1   1   2     3     2,3
2   2   2     NULL  2,3
3   3   NULL  3     2,3
4   4   NULL  3     2,3
5   5   10    11    10,11
```

for example,If any col1 and col2 has 2 or 3, the new column need to contain both values.Not sure how to capture if col1 or col2 has NULLs.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns? Could you provide a MRE to produce the input? Is it `df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2, 2, np.nan, 10], "col2": [3, np.nan, 3, 11]})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffill` to fill NaNs convert to int, then str, then `join` on axis:

```
df['combine'] = df[['col1','col2']].ffill().astype(int).astype(str).apply(','.join, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id1  id2  col1  col2 combine
0    1    1   2.0   3.0     2,3
1    2    2   2.0   NaN     2,3
2    3    3   NaN   3.0     2,3
3    4    4  10.0  11.0   10,11
```